# How to see the python mysql prepared sql before execute?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using the cursor prepared execute feature of the python mysql connector: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html

I seem to have an error in my prepared statement - is there a way to see the final, prepared sql statement that is sent to the mysql server?

Comment: You can look wrong queries in MySQL error log

Comment: Filling in the parameters is done by the server, not the client.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev thanks but it does not look like MySQL logs any failed queries.